# npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^2.0.0, required by ng2-translate@5.0.0

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How can I fix this error when I made a npm list?

package.json

https://www.paste.org/97809

`npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^2.0.0, required by ng2-translate@5.0.0`

`npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/http@^2.0.0, required by ng2-translate@5.0.0`

Comment: Can you add you package.json file ?

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha `https ://paste .ofcode.org/ 5FzrB5jN 6JP4VGUk9B98Pn`

Comment: https://www.paste.org/97809

Answer (score 0):

That's obvious, you are using Angular 5, while ng2-translate was an old library built for Angular 2.

You should better update your `ng2-translate` dependency and replace it with `ngx-translate`:  https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

It's the same library which is supported by Angular 5 and +

EDIT: According to the table on Github (8.x to 9.x for angular 5), so you'd better use the 9.1.1 version according to the releases tab. In your package.json file replace the ng2-transate and any ngx-translate entries with this one:

```
"@ngx-translate/core": "9.1.1"
```

PS: Welcome to StackOverflow :). If it doesn't work call the 911 (vine to ref ngx translate version xD)

Comment: thank you very much for your review and I'm going to say the result

Comment: 911 I will call :(

Comment: npm ERR! missing: @ngx-translate/core@9.1.1, required by Cellstore@1.0.1 error the end

Answer (score 0):

You need to update packages by simply these commands.

- List item

npm i @angular/core

npm i @angular/http

Answer (score 0):

npm ERR! missing: @ngx-translate/core@9.1.1, required by Cellstore@1.0.1

Last ERROR

package.json  ? package-lock.json ?

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha  Last ERROR package.json ? package-lock.json ?